# Role-based access not working in .net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization, roles

I want only the users having the admin role to access a page, Create. However, none of the users, both having roles admin or user can access the page.  Below is my controller code:

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View("Admin/Create");
    }
```

As you can see, Create is in a sub-folder, Admin.  I also tried with create a separate web.config, in this sub-folder to control access, but in vain.  My web.config code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="admin"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

My model user, does have a Roles property.  Any idea what I am missing?

Added:
My root web.config:

```
<system.web>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".cshtml" loginUrl="~/Home/Login" />
</authentication>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Did you set <authentication> tag  in web config?

Comment: In the root, web.config yes.  I have added the code in the question.

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Identity? if not, where are you getting your roles from? and who is responsible of setting them?

Comment: In any case using authorization tag in web config is not advised. You should be able to apply authorization logic through Attributes and global filters

Comment: I am not using asp.net Identity.  The model, User, has a property, Roles.  I am getting the roles from this property.

Comment: Ok, I removed the authorization tag in web config.  But it still will not allow access to admin users.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92691/discussion-between-alex-art-and-tabby).